# Why is my main preview of the shader graphs pink?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, urp

I recently learn the basics of shader graphs and am trying to explore some of the shader graphs.

But I encountered a problem, my main preview of the shader is pink:

[image: screenshot]

**FYI**: I used URP Lit

And it does the same with the object in the scene when I changed the materials to my shader. I've tried to follow the youtube tutorial on how to fix this issue too but it didn't seem to work for me.

**How can I fix this issue?**

Thank you for reading this far!! have a nice day!!:)

Comment: If this is happening to all your shaders, it might be an issue of your graphics card being too old.

Comment: _[Why are all materials pink in my Unity URP project?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/187729/why-are-all-materials-pink-in-my-unity-urp-project)_